# Is it possible to replace the electrolytic capacitor in a full wave rectifier bridge with a ceramic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, ac-dc, bridge-rectifier, electrolytic-capacitor

Why do we use electrolytic capacitors in full wave rectifier bridges? Is it because we can have huge capacitance with electrolytic type or is it because the output is DC voltage where polarity is a concern?

Comment: the polarity of electrolytic caps is a *restriction* and not a feature. but they offer plenty of other advantages which is why people still use them.

Comment: Ceramic capacitors work best at low voltage and their capacity decreases as voltage increases. Try specing out a 400v rated MLCC and you'll see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

All capacitors have their pro's and con's for specific applications.  There is no one capacitor type that is the best all around cap.  If there were, it would make our lives much easier.

General characteristics:
**Electrolytics** are characterized by high density and good high voltage values.  This makes them desirable for use after a bridge rectifier.  However, they are a "wet" capacitor and are subject to drying out over time.  When they dry out they no longer have the capacitance, low resistance properties.

**Ceramic** are characterized by very, very low resistance and low inductance (parasitic properties).  They however have lower capacitance values and have a voltage bias effect.

To use ceramic capacitors after a bridge rectifier, you will need to use several of them in parallel to get the capacitance needed, and to make sure that with the bias effect, they still add up to the amount needed.

Comment: Another potential "gotcha" is the lower ESR or equivalent-series resistance of ceramic, especially when putting lots of them in parallel to match the electrolytic's capacitance.  An elect may have 1Ω of ESR, equating to an inrush current limit of say 12A.  But replace that with 50 ceramics in parallel, and that total ESR might be 1mΩ, so the surge current would be 1200A theoretically... pop goes the bridge rectifier or traces on the board.

Comment: There is usually enough external series resistance and inductance in rectifiers, wiring, and transformers, to limit actual surge current to much less than theoretical values that don't take these into account. Diodes and other semiconductors have surge ratings and safe operating areas for current pulses ten or more times nominal rating. And circuit board traces can handle hundreds of amps for short durations without damage. It takes a lot of energy to vaporize a PCB trace.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use an electrolytic capacitor in a full wave bridge rectifier, you use diodes. The filter capacitor is not part of the rectifier.

That aside, the reason for using electrolytics for the filter caps in power supplies (and the rectifier type doesn't matter, half wave, full wave, bridge, electrolytics are used with all of them) is simply because they're the most cost efficient way to get a lot of capacitance in a small volume, and they're good enough for the intended purpose, filtering out the low frequency ripple.

Comment: Actually, there is a very good reason not to use electrolytics when cost/space/weight are not driving the decision. And that reason is lifespan.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Are we only talking about the traditional electroylytics which have liquid inside or the new solid polymer electrolytics? Because those have nothing to dry out.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't know about all solid polymer electrolytic capacitors, but this Panasonic polymer Aluminum e-cap has a 4000 hour endurance rating. Will it last longer? Probably, but to me, such an endurance rating suggests a need for replacement/maintenance much sooner than many other types of components. https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/244451

Answer (score 1):

Of course it might be possible to use ceramic in place of electrolytics.

Polarity is not a concern as ceramics don't have polarity.

But depending on the capacitor requirements, you may not be able to find a ceramic capacitor with matching voltage and capacitance rating, so you simply put a large enough electrolytic in the circuit.

Comment: Fascinatingly, there are poled ceramics, which have maximum capacitance within an offset (signed) voltage. They are definitely not what you're likely to encounter, though; still very much a boutique item, as far as I know!

Answer (score 0):

It may be assumed that this is a power supply running on 50 or 60 Hz line frequency, and that the output is perhaps 6 to 24 VDC and a load current of 100 mA or more. In that case, the capacitor would need to be in the order of several hundred to several thousand uF, to store energy and maintain a minimum voltage during times where the rectified voltage approaches zero at the zero crossings. As explained in other answers, such capacitors are only available as electrolytic, and their properties of fairly high equivalent series resistance (ESR) are actually beneficial for reducing surge current to reasonable values.

In cases where the applied AC voltage is in the kHz or MHz range, as in switching supplies, capacitance values can be much smaller for a given load current, and ceramic or film capacitors with low ESR are needed to accommodate the high frequency. When the applied voltage is a square wave, there is very little "dead time" at zero crossing, so smaller capacitors will work.

In either case, ceramic or film capacitors are often used in parallel with electrolytics to provide a low impedance source for loads which operate at high frequencies, such as logic circuits and processors.